# MySQL connection node

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, phpmyadmin, apache2

I'm running my node app on a linux vps where I have installed apache2 and phpmyadmin. I have my mysql database on the server there which I can connect to user the `mysql -uusername -ppassword` command, but when running my node app with this code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '*******',
    database : 'db_name',
});

connection.connect(function(e) {
    if(e) {
        console.log('Database didn\'t connect');
    } else {
        console.log('Database connected successfully');
    }
});
```

It says "database didn't connect". the user, password and db fields are all correct for sure.

When console.log(e) I'm getting:

I'm getting:
error code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE'
errorno: 1251
sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client'.

anybody knows why ?

Comment: try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`. MySQL treats `localhost` like a unix socket instead of a tcp connection and this is what `mysql -uuseraname..` does by default.

Comment: Tried that too already, but it didn't work.. ty anyway.

Comment: I also tried my public ip, didn't work

Comment: what happens if you print out e? Maybe it has more information

Comment: I'm getting: 
error code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE'
errorno: 1251
sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client'.

Comment: could it be https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2377 ? What does `show create user username` show? What MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the connection to use the unix socket or check the mysqld is binding on 0.0.0.0 or on the ip of the ethernet card of the server it's running on.
According to the mysqld version you're using, the option can be "skip-networking" or "bind-address".